# readdir nor funciona con directorio llamados "0"

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código de PHP donde a través opendir y readdir recorro todos los elementos de un directorio.

```
// Leo todos los ficheros de la carpeta
$bDir = opendir($secondLevel);

while($B = readdir($bDir)){

   // Imprimir nombre en una línea diferente
   $this->line($B);

}
```

En el directorio en cuestión, me he fijado que cuando existe otro directorio llamado "0", el resultado del while es siempre . y .. pero nunca el resto de directorios que hay dentro.

Ejemplo: Cuando dentro del directorio que vamos a recorrer existen las carpetas "x", "z" la salida es la siguiente:

```
.
..
x
z
```

Sin embargo, cuando renombro el directorio x por 0, la salida es la siguiente:

```
.
..
```

No aparece el 0 pero tampoco z ¿A alguien le ha pasado algo parecido?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto se tiene ya en cuenta en al documentación de la función [readdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php):

> Please note the fashion in which readdir()'s return value is checked in the examples below. We are explicitly testing whether the return value is identical to (equal to and of the same type as--see Comparison Operators for more information) false since otherwise, any directory entry whose name evaluates to false will stop the loop (e.g. a directory named "0").

El bucle se detiene al encontrar el directorio llamado `0` ya que el bucle se detiene cuando `readdir` devuelve `false` por el `while`. En este caso tienes que evaluar que el valor devuelto sea distinto al `booleano` `false`. Esto se hace con  el [operador](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) `!==` que no solo evalúa el valor sino también el tipo de dato. Esto quiere decir que si usas el operador `!=` tendrías el mismo problema ya que `0` y `false` serían una negación aunque sean de distinto tipo.

Debes evaluar que la condición sea distinta a `false`, por lo que en tu caso quedaría así (tal y como comenta la documentación para hacerlo de forma correcta):

```
while(false !== ($B = readdir($bDir))) {

   // Imprimir nombre en una línea diferente
   $this->line($B);

}
```

Comment: Toda la razón, gracias !